# Serializing structs

Tags: c++, serialization, struct

I'm working on a homework project and i'm trying to store inventory data into a file.

The inventory data size shouldn't be too large cause technically no one is going to really use it.

**I need to write these contents to a file:**

• Item Description
• Quantity on Hand 
• Wholesale Cost 
• Retail Cost 
• Date Added to Inventory

**I am going to need to make an interface that allows me to do this:**

• Add new records to the file
• Display any record in the file 
• Change any record in the file

Struct would be the easiest way to go about this imo. If I can just figure out how to read / write structs to a file this should be really easy.

If you could provide a small example on how to do this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IOStream library** does it

> The [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/) class provides the interface to write data to files as output streams.
>
> The [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) class provides the interface to read data from files as input streams

Edit-  [Example](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_079.html)

Comment: I see how you could write a structure to a file with "write" using ofstream. But how would you read it back in ?

Comment: with the ifstream...you would first use the ifstream to read a file, it can be blank..then write to the same file

Comment: Can you show me a example on how to do this? Just a small one ?

Comment: Good link, that helped me a lot. Now I just have to see if I can get this example you provided to work.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your teacher, could you use boost library.
If yes, read boost serilization tutorial, it contains a simple examples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

But if you want understand how to work with files, you should do this works without any help or boost.

If you want works with std::[io]fstreams you should decide what format you will support:
- text - for this case best way define operator<< and operator>> and use them for writing structure to file or reading;
- binary - your structure should be POD ( plain old data ) and doesn't should contain pointers - and you will use read and write streams methods.
example for binary file:
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=269648

Comment: No I don't think he wants us to use any extra librarys. I plan on doing this by myself, I just need to understand how to read & write structs or XML's to a file !!! lol

Comment: except a raw dump of the structure, it will be easier to use a lib of some kind than to roll your own.

Comment: In life usualy it easy and better using well deigned third party lib instead investigating bicycle. But If you want understand low level - you sohuld use std::[io]fstreams.

Comment: Alright I will see what I can do with them. I just wish someone gave me an example on how to use them!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind really low level, you can just bit copy the structs in and out by casting a pointer to the struct to `void*` and using `sizeof()` to get the struct length. (IIRC their is a way to dump/read a void buffer to/from a file)

---

Note this ONLY works if the data has no pointers/references/etc.

---

I like [C's IO](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node18.html) better than C++'s so:

```
typedef struct { int hi; int mon; char[35] dat; } S;

S s;
S arr[22];
int f;
```

---

```
  // write
f = open(/* I forget the args*/);

  // one
if(sizeof(s) != write(f, &s, sizeof(s))) Error();
  // many
if(sizeof(arr) != write(f, arr, sizeof(arr))) Error();

close(f);
```

---

```
  // read
f = open(/* I forget the args*/);

  // one
if(sizeof(s) != read(f, &s, sizeof(s))) Error();
  // many
if(sizeof(arr) != read(f, arr, sizeof(arr))) Error();

close(f);
```

Comment: I REALLY like your idea. Could you provide a short example of how to do this?

Comment: @BCS: ANSI/ISO C's IO is 'fopen', 'fread', 'fwrite'. 'open', 'read', 'write' are POSIX/K&R C. Oh, and 'open' looks like 'open("newfile.dat", O_CREAT | O_BINARY)' or 'open("log.txt", O_RDONLY | O_TEXT)'.

Comment: So it is that easy? What if the integer value is 250259 instead of 2509 wouldn't the size of "s" change making the read in not work ?

Comment: I know that the open/read/write it not the streamIO stuff. If all you are doing is reading binary blobs then the POSIX stuff is enough for me.

Comment: @OneShot: int is 32 bits long no mater what (unless it's 16 or 64 bits but that depends on the compiler). OTOH don't expect to read the resultant file with a text editor.

Comment: How do I know when to stop, and read the next Struct? THis file will save multiple structs to the file.

Comment: @OneShot; You will need to figure out what order the structs are in during reading your self but running more than one read/write in a row will work and end-of-file can be detected by the given `if` statment.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with XML; it's structured, it's text based so you can look at it with any text editor.

Comment: How do I do that.... can you give me an example on how I would read and right that to a file ?